# Android app instantly crashes

Tags: android

```
    11-12 13:31:44.988: D/AndroidRuntime(13055): Shutting down VM
11-12 13:31:44.988: W/dalvikvm(13055): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d570)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.StickmanRevolution/com.example.StickmanRevolution.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.StickmanRevolution.activity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.StickmanRevolution-2.apk]
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.StickmanRevolution.activity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.StickmanRevolution-2.apk]
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055):    ... 11 more
```

I have been trying to get this to work for almost a week. I have ready MANY threads, and have tried everything I could find. I cannot figure out why my app will not work at all. I have tried both the emulator and my android phone.

Answer (score 1):

This is your error:

> 11-12 13:31:45.008: E/AndroidRuntime(13055): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.StickmanRevolution.activity.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.StickmanRevolution-2.apk]

Android cannot find the class `com.example.StickmanRevolution.activity.MainActivity`. Make sure that your classes are in the correct package, and that the name matches exactly (including case).

Comment: Also make sure the name of the class is correct in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Wow, I made a dumb mistake. The name was right in the manifest, I just made a typo in the name of the actual one. Thanks for the help.